# Google speech api Credentials Not Working

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I've enabled the Google text-to-speech api, generated an oAuth2 file and an api key, and when I run the code below from localhost and execution hits the "$textToSpeechClient =" line, both return the same error ("Could not load the default credentials.").  I would prefer using the api key (in the commented out section), but I'll use either one.  I installed the PHP client using Composer.

I tried getting paid support from Google, but I'm not able to sign up because "You must be assigned Support > Support Account Administrator for the organization in IAM to continue."  When I go there, there is no apparent way to do that.

Help on any of these fronts would be appreciated.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '\googleAuthorization.json');

use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

// $client->setDeveloperKey("AIzaSyAzSZjgfLS76q1234abcdefgtoGuKAqz5xE");
// $client->addScope(Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE);
// $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
// $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
// if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
//     $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
// }

$textToSpeechClient = new TextToSpeechClient();
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you got including the error number if there is any?

Comment: I created a new domain through Google, signed up for a new workspace, used a different email address, a different credit card.  My name and phone number were the same.  I get the same credentials error, and when I try to get support (willing to pay), I'm told to see my administrator (and I'm the only one involved).  Trying AWS.

Comment: You may try this approach 
 https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-php in authenticating your API code.

Comment: @Scott B.  I'll post an answer when I get it.  I found out how to get paid ($30/mo) Google support!  Even though I'm the "owner", I have to give myself the "role" of "Support Admin."  I tried everything the page above described BTW and the error remained unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved (with the help of 3 google support staff in a video chat in at least 3 different time zones).

The Google text-to-speech api **requires** that the PHP command:

```
putdev()
```

be available so you can run:

```
putenv(
  "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=absolute-path-to-your-json-authentication-file.json"
);
```

In my default *php.ini* server configuration, *putdev* was included in the rather long *disable_functions=* list.  Removing putdev from that list allowed authentication to proceed as expected.

Why this is needed for the text-to-speech api and not the cloud storage api is still a mystery.